# ubuntu 16 - wifi unbale to scan my own ssid, but able to scan others people ssid

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, intel-wireless

I am new to Ubuntu.

First problem:
I have just install Ubuntu 16. when I enable Wi-Fi, only my neighbor SSID name is appear on the drop down column.  I cannot see my own SSID.

Second problem:
Then, I create new WiFi network.

I key in a connection name: `wifiwork1`, network name `wifiwork`.  Then Wi-Fi security: WEP 128-bit passphrase and finally my key. I will show connected when click create.

However, when I check the Connection information, it is all wrong.  The address is wrong --> IP Address is `10.42.0.1`, suppose to be `192.168.0.xxx`.  Broadcast Address is `10.42.0.255`, also wrong.  The General information is `802.11 WiFi (wlp11s0)`, hardware Address is `00:13:02:54:FC:34` , driver is `iwl3945`, Speed: unknown and security is WEP.

Third problem: 
When I login to internet, it shows server cannot found.

Comment: oh ya,.., My actually router is configure as the following:  Wireless security mode is Enable WPA/WPA2 Wireless Security (enhanced),  Cipher Type is AUTO (TKIP/AES),  PSK/EAP is PSK, Network key is  8~63 ASCII or 64 HEX.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, I create new WiFi network.
>
> I key in a connection name: wifiwork1, network name wifiwork. Then
>   Wi-Fi security: WEP 128-bit passphrase and finally my key. I will show
>   connected when click create.
>
> However, when I check the Connection information, it is all wrong. The
>   address is wrong --> IP Address is 10.42.0.1, suppose to be
>   192.168.0.xxx

"Create New Wi-Fi Network" is intended for computer-to-computer; that is, ad-hoc connections. That is not what you want. Please remove all those settings and restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Make certain that your wireless interface is not set to ad-hoc:

```
iwconfig
```

It should read: *Mode: Managed*. If not, change it:

```
sudo iwconfig wlp11s0 mode managed
```

> My actually router is configure as the following: Wireless security
>   mode is Enable WPA/WPA2 Wireless Security (enhanced), Cipher Type is
>   AUTO (TKIP/AES), PSK/EAP is PSK, Network key is 8~63 ASCII or 64 HEX.

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Reboot the router and the computer and check:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

Do you see your network?

Comment: Thanks chilli555.  Thank you very much for your reply. I try it out this morning and the wifi works normally. since I am still new in Ubuntu, I am not trying out any suggested command at the moment.  I will check out your command later.  Now I will try out my wired Ethernet, the same notebook (dell inspiron 6400), some Linux, same problem ( canot even connect).  I will update and upgrade using my wifi and then connect to internet through wired.  See the problem still exist.  Many thanks to you.

Comment: For your information, for the wifi part, I have not done anything additionally this morning for it to work normally.  therefore, I do not know the rot cause and how it is fixed.  Thank you very much.